# How can I scroll normally on Excel without row border automatically snapping to top?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Currently, when I scroll through my excel document, all rows' top border automatically snap to top of document. I want to scroll normally without this happening. How can I set this?

Comment: have you tried to unfreeze the panes

Comment: Unfreeze panes doesnt want. I think that is the one that keeps rows and columns visible while the rest of the worksheet scrolls (from desc)

Comment: Why do you want to scroll in that manner? What's the benefit?

Comment: I cannot resize some rows because of this scrolling.

Comment: Actually I just fixed that using zoom though its just a small hack.

Comment: (1) Freeze panes keeps rows and columns visible. Unfreeze panes removes any such setup. (2) Is this happening only one one excel file or on every file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible. I have tried to change this behaviour previously but without success.

Comment: Its very annoying. This is preventing me from resizing some of the rows.